# Discrepancies between Android's various ways to access assets via AssetManager

Tags: android

I'm a beginner Android programmer who has run into a weird issue with using the various methods for reading assets from the AssetManager.

I've attached sample code below that exhibits this issue.  It reads a simple text file asset ("hello.txt") that contains "hello".  I read it in as raw bytes and print out the hexadecimal values of the characters (68 65 6c 6c 6f).

The ways I've tried are (in order in the code):

- open AssetFileDescriptor (AFD), create InputStream: only reads in the first three bytes (68 65 6c ffffffff ffffffff)
- open AFD, get underlying file descriptor, create FileInputStream: completely wrong data (50 4b 3 4 a)
- open InputStream directly: correct (68 65 6c 6c 6f)

I've also repeated the same three methods, this time reading into a byte array first, which (surprisingly!) changes the first result but otherwise yields the same results (repeated here for convenience):

- open AFD, create InputStream, read into byte array first: correct (68 65 6c 6c 6f)
- open AFD, get underlying file descriptor, create FileInputStream, read into byte array first: completely wrong data (50 4b 3 4 a)
- open InputStream directly, read into byte array first: correct (68 65 6c 6c 6f)

Note that, with the exception of the very first case (when only three bytes are read in), the other cases read exactly 6 bytes (including the newline at the end) and will subsequently return -1 afterwards as expected.  This includes those cases where wrong data is read in.

Has anyone run into this before?  Is this a bug, or did I do something wrong?

Thanks!

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    AssetManager am = getAssets();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        AssetFileDescriptor afd = am.openFd("hello.txt"); 
        InputStream instream = afd.createInputStream();
        sb.append(String.format("afd.createInputStream(): %x %x %x %x %x\n", instream.read(), instream.read(), instream.read(), instream.read(), instream.read()));
        instream.close();
        afd.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    try {
        AssetFileDescriptor afd = am.openFd("hello.txt");
        InputStream instream = new FileInputStream(afd.getFileDescriptor());
        sb.append(String.format("new FileInputStream(afd): %x %x %x %x %x\n", instream.read(), instream.read(), instream.read(), instream.read(), instream.read()));
        instream.close();
        afd.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    try {
        InputStream instream = am.open("hello.txt");
        sb.append(String.format("am.open(): %x %x %x %x %x\n", instream.read(), instream.read(), instream.read(), instream.read(), instream.read()));
        instream.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    try {
        AssetFileDescriptor afd = am.openFd("hello.txt");
        InputStream instream = afd.createInputStream();
        byte[] b = new byte[instream.available()];
        instream.read(b);
        sb.append(String.format("afd.createInputStream() -> byte[]: %x %x %x %x %x\n", b[0], b[1], b[2], b[3], b[4]));
        instream.close();
        afd.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    try {
        AssetFileDescriptor afd = am.openFd("hello.txt");
        InputStream instream = new FileInputStream(afd.getFileDescriptor());
        byte[] b = new byte[(int) afd.getLength()];
        instream.read(b);
        sb.append(String.format("new FileInputStream(afd) -> byte[]: %x %x %x %x %x\n", b[0], b[1], b[2], b[3], b[4]));
        instream.close();
        afd.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    try {
        InputStream instream = am.open("hello.txt");
        byte[] b = new byte[instream.available()];
        instream.read(b);
        sb.append(String.format("am.open() -> byte[]: %x %x %x %x %x\n", b[0], b[1], b[2], b[3], b[4]));
        instream.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    // print result
    TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
    textview.setText(sb.toString());
    Log.d("blah", sb.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the InputStream from the app's BaseContext.  The example below demonstrates getting a txt file from the assets folder and printing its contents to the console.

```
    try {
        InputStream in = getBaseContext().getResources().getAssets().open("sample.txt");
        InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(in);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(is);
        String read=br.readLine();

        while(read != null) {
            System.out.println(read);
            read = br.readLine();
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Hey Mike, thanks for the reply.  I believe the method you are proposing is the one that I tried that consistently works (the method I refer to as "opening an InputStream directly").

However, my question is not so much which way is the best way, but rather why the other ways (which I believe should also work in theory) do not seem to work.